Did Esteban kill Justo or not?
I've just read Juan Rulfo's short story "At daybreak" ("En la madrugada"), part of the collection The Burning Plain and Other Stories (whose Spanish original is available online with George D. Schade's English translation freely available to borrow from the Internet Archive). It's told largely from two viewpoints, those of old Esteban the cowherd and Don Justo Brambila, where the former is now on trial for allegedly killing the latter. But what actually happened?

Esteban keeps saying that maybe he killed the other man and doesn't remember it. Are we meant to surmise that that's what happened? After all, his description of what he did to the calf seems much less severe than the way it's described from Justo's viewpoint.
But even Justo's viewpoint doesn't seem to describe Esteban fighting back, only that he blacked out while beating the old man. Esteban mentions "he might've died from anger too"; is this the interpretation we're meant to follow?
Or is the story just written to keep us wondering, without any clear resolution?

Maybe I'm too dense to understand literature of Rulfo's quality. The preceding story, "The man", confused me a lot at first too, but I was able to piece the events together after re-reading it. Or maybe there are hints in the original Spanish version that weren't preserved well enough in translation?

The short answer to the question is that we don’t know who or what killed Don Justo. It is one of the unanswered questions that Rulfo leaves us with. This corresponds to the third interpretation given in the question "the story [is] just written to keep us wondering, without any clear resolution", or as Hugo Rodríguez Alcalá notes in his analysis of the story:

Rulfo does not want things to be clear. He does not explain them nor
does he give the reader sufficient clues… Rulfo's art seems to take
pleasure in a suggestive ambiguity, in a mysterious blur

and then dispenses the sage advice, “Do not look for more clarity than that offered”.
Rulfo divides the story into eight sections, separated by blank spaces. The first and the last sections - the introduction and conclusion - mirror each other by describing the fog and cloud which bathe the scene in which the events occur. The story is thus explicitly framed by nebulosity, echoing the ambiguities present in the narrative itself.
The fourth section is written from the point of view of old Esteban, who tells us how Don Justo attacked him: "he gave me such a beating that I was almost out cold among the rocks". He claims not to remember anything else, declaring: "I remember well up to the moment I hit the calf and the boss came at me, up to there I remember very well; afterward everything is hazy...“ This lack of memory, genuine or feigned, means that we can learn nothing from him about the nature of Don Justo's death.
In the next section, the unnamed narrator (i.e. Rulfo) takes over the story, and tells what happen to Don Justo on the morning of his death. The section concludes with the narrator's view of the incident we have already seen through Esteban’s eyes. The two versions coincide factually: in both descriptions Esteban brutally punishes the calf and Don Justo defends it. In this section it is Rulfo who describes the attack, and, putting himself inside Don Justo, tells how the latter's head becomes cloudy and completely dark, and he dies. What is not told from either of these points of view is how the death occurred. Neither Rulfo — who must know everything — nor Esteban, who may have an interest in keeping quiet about part of the events, explains how Don Justo came to die. Instead the narrator allows the reader to draw their own conclusions.
Why would Rulfo tell the episode of the calf and the subsequent violence twice? This way of narrating in parts, leaving details in the shadows, is a technique he also employed in the preceding short story The Man. It has the effect of stimulating the reader's imagination, sometimes confusing and disorientating it, and forcing it to work actively. Esteban refuses to confess to having killed Don Justo - he appears genuinely baffled as to how it happened. To tackle this riddle, the reader must imagine the scene of the murder for themself, in order to see the victim kill his attacker. Instead of being a rather humdrum whodunnit set in Mexico, the story is instead a drama in which the reader is compelled to resolve the ambiguites for themself, as best they can.
